# MobX - Observable object grabbing only changed fields?

Tags: mobx

I have a MobX store setup with an observable object that has default values, and whose values gets populated from the server on load of react native scene. I have a list of observable user preferences in the `UserPreferencesStore` like this:

```
class UserPreferencesStore {
    @observable userPreferences = {
        receive_upvotes_mail: 0,
        receive_answers_mail: 0,
        receive_comments_mail: 0
    }
}
```

On the RN side, these values change to this:

```
class UserPreferencesStore {
    @observable userPreferences = {
        receive_upvotes_mail: 1,
        receive_answers_mail: 1,
        receive_comments_mail: 0
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to get **only the changed items** to send to the server. Any idea? Also, is this the most efficient way to use mobx for this situation, an observable object, even if I have 20 fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be a matter of establishing a separate autorun or reaction for each field:

```
class UserPreferencesStore {
    @observable userPreferences = {
        receive_upvotes_mail: 1,
        receive_answers_mail: 1,
        receive_comments_mail: 0
    }

    constructor() {
        Object.keys(this.userPreferences).forEach(setting => {
            reaction(
                // whenever a new value is produced...
                () => this.userPreferences[setting],
                // ..run this effect
                (newValue) => storeSettingOnServer(setting, newValue)
            )
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer, please keep it as it is useful, but I have 2 issues. 1. As soon as the class runs, the constructor stores on the server. Is there any way to have it not store the defaults until the data has actually changed? I tested this by an alert(setting) under // .. run this effect, and it alerted each key before anything changed. 2. This works for on the spot changes, change field and it submits to server right away, but how can it work with a save button instead? Where if you make changes, only the changed fields are sent to server on hitting save?

Comment: 1. See the docs, reaction will skip the effect the first time. 2 Use the same mechanism, but instead store the pending changes in memory and send the pending changes to the server once the button is clicked

Comment: Thank you, will explore further :)